# Java Spring Boot MVC and CLI API in the same project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, architecture

Java Spring Boot MVC and CLI API in the same project

I have implemented a web app using Spring Boot MVC and I now I need to add an API whose functions can be called from a cronjob. 
I would like to use Entity and Repository classes implemented in my Web app. I was thinking about creating a new main class which implements 
CommandLineRunner interface and then create separate JARS for Web and CLI applications and run them independently. Is this a good approach?
Do you have any suggestion about the architecture?

Thanks

Comment: Just send a http request from your cron job to your web server (using HTTPie or curl). The cron job will just be one additional client of your web application.

Answer (score 1):

Concur with comment from @jb-nizet - `cron` is really just another client of your application, and using a (`bash`,etc.) script wrapping `curl`, `httpie`, or `wget` to call the controller is a good solution.

Advantages include:

- can be called remotely
- doesn't add complexity to the application
- application boundary/interface remains the same
- doesn't add a new application (except a relatively trivial script)
- not tied to `cron` - could be almost any other application

Considerations:

- authentication (if needed) and the management of credentials in the script/cron
- if all methods/actions needed for cron are new and different to existing functions in the web app, do they make sense to be encoded in the webapp?

Comment: Thanks for a prompt response! As @jb-nizet suggested, I will try with sending a HTTP request from a cron. Actually, it is very convenient for me to have it implemented as a Web API, I just thought that making an HTTP request from a cron is not a good practice.

Comment: One could argue that cron is a bad idea in its own right...

If the schedule is fixed and rarely needs to be changed, then it could be encoded in the app itself (https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/). Or If you have an enterprise scheduling solution, that could be used. Additional considerations I left out is how the success/failure/output of the scheduled operation is monitored, how the scheduling portion gets deployed, and what the maintenance/operation (e.g. rescheduling/restarts) needs and processes are.

Nice thing about calling remotely is that integ with ChatOps is viable.